# jQuery localStorage if exists save it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the localStorage method.
I have this code:

```
player = $('#player').val();
team   = $('input[name="team"]:checked').val();
```

then I tried to storage it and show it even if the page is refreshed

```
var a = localStorage.setItem('managername', player);
var b = localStorage.setItem('managerteam', team);

$('#tournament').append(a b);
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

`setItem` does not return the value. You need to use `getItem` to retrieve the values after they have been saved. Also note that you need to concatenate `a` and `b` in the `append` (or append them separately).

```
// save
localStorage.setItem('managername', player);
localStorage.setItem('managerteam', team);

// retrieve
var a = localStorage.getItem('managername');
var b = localStorage.getItem('managerteam');    
$('#tournament').append(a + ' ' + b);
```

Comment: I upvoted this but I honestly have no idea if it answered whatever question the OP is after.

Comment: @Marc me too, but given the logic in her code it seems the most likely thing that she was trying to achieve.

Comment: So i have those 2 vars that i wrote: player and team - that i want to getItem into the DOM and save it:

Comment: You have to save them first. I've updated my answer to make it a little clearer for you.

Comment: Yes well that's exactly what i did, I'm just asking how can i save it even if the page is refreshed?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - once they are saved they will persist across page refreshes until the cache is cleared, or you remove them using `removeItem()` or `clear()`

Comment: it will storage until the cache is cleared, but it won't append it, when i refresh the page i see nothing, i guess it's because i need to write something like, if the storage exists - keep it, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 gives you 2 types of storage options

> 1. Local Storage - stores data with no expiration date, unless you explicitly clear it
> 2. Session Storage - stores data for one session (data is lost
>          when the tab is closed)

So if you want to persist data between page refreshes, use **Local Storage**. You need to check for that if your browser supports it like this

```
if(window.localStorage){
  // now we have local storage support
  var storage =  window.localStorage;
  storage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
}
```

similarly when you wan't to retrieve do the same check

```
if(window.localStorage){
  // now we have local storage support
  var storage =  window.localStorage;
  var name = storage.getItem("lastname");
  console.log(name);
}
```

if you wan't to delete items from local storage, use removeItem('urIdentifier)

Instead of setItem() and getItem(), you can even use dot(.) notation

```
// store
storage.lastName = "smith";
// retrieve
alert(storage.lastName);
```

In case you need more details, look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

EDIT :

```
$('.urAddBtn').on('click',function(){
    var player = $('#player').val(),
        team   = $('input[name="team"]:checked').val();
    if(window.localStorage){
      /* now we have local storage support in the browser
         get the local storage instance */
      var storage =  window.localStorage; 
      // save items to storage
      storage.setItem('managername', player);
      storage.setItem('managerteam', team);
    }
});
```

---

Some where else when you click on remove icon

```
$('.removeBtn').on('click',function(){
    if(window.localStorage){
      /* now we have local storage support in the browser
         get the local storage instance */
      var storage =  window.localStorage; 
      // remove items from local storage
      storage.removeItem('managername');
      storage.removeItem('managerteam');
    }
});
```

Comment: I feel like you're just copying those explanation from other websites and don't understand what i need. my main question is how do i save the localstorage on the webpage, if i append it, i want it to stay on the webpage even if the page is refreshed, please.. it's should be simpler than your code

Comment: As a matter of fact, there's no question posted in your description. I just inferred this from this title :) Like i explained it already, local storage will be persisted between page refreshes. So you can have a script running in page1 add some times to it and page2 script can retrieve those items or even page1 script can access those saved items after a reload. The only concern is all those pages should be from same host

Comment: Wait, i don't understand ? what do you mean there's no question in my post? I asked it 3 times, How can append it so it will be saved on the page even if it's refreshed? please :(

Comment: look again ;) it's not there in the main description, may be u mentioned in comments. By the way did u get ur answer ?

Comment: i believe if i say: "then I tried to storage it and show it" - show it means to 'append it', anyway.. i still stuck and need an answer for that, can you help me? do you know what i need, or should i explain it again?

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding your question. You have 2 vars `player & team`, you already saved them to local storage, now you refreshed the page, u want to check if these player, team values are already there in the local storage. If they're available, get those values and add it to some element with id `tournament`. Is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: I have an input text for the user the enter the player name, and a radio button to choose a team, when the user select both of them i want to append it to the table (as a row) that i have, now it's working fine, but i wanted the data to be saved so i thought it will be easy to do it with localStorage, then i can also add a little remove icon button to remove from storage

Comment: Are you doing private lessons? i really need it, if you interested please private message me